# Formatting epoch time

Tags: solaris, ksh

I have this command, which I found [here](http://solarisjedi.blogspot.com/2006/06/solaris-date-command-and-epoch-time.html):

```
/usr/bin/truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | 
    nawk -F= '/^time\(\)/ {gsub(/" "/,"",$2);printf "0t%d=Y\n", $2-30*86400}' |
    adb
```

which prints `2014 Jan 11 09:48:54`.  Does anyone know how to reformat the output to YYYYMMDDHH?

I have to use ksh on Solaris.  I can't use perl.

Comment: I should link this onto the meta.stackoverflow.com "XY question" ... why can't you simply call `date +"%Y%m%d%H"` (which directly gives the `YYYYMMDDHH` output, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/date.html for the possibilities of the format specification) ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments:

- the first command:

  ```
  /usr/bin/truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 |
  nawk -F= '/^time\(\)/ {gsub(/" "/,"",$2);printf "0t%d=Y\n", $2-30*86400}'
  ```

might be replaced by the much lighter and simpler

```
   nawk 'BEGIN {printf("0t%d=Y\n",srand()-30*86400)}'`
```

- I'm not sure `adb` is understanding the `0txx=Y` syntax but `mdb` definitely does.

That said, here is something that should fit your needs:

```
nawk 'BEGIN {printf("0t%d=Y\n",srand()-30*86400)}' | mdb | nawk '
function m2m(m)
{
    if(m=="Jan")return 1
    if(m=="Feb")return 2
    if(m=="Mar")return 3
    if(m=="Apr")return 4
    if(m=="May")return 5
    if(m=="Jun")return 6
    if(m=="Jul")return 7
    if(m=="Aug")return 8
    if(m=="Sep")return 9
    if(m=="Oct")return 10
    if(m=="Nov")return 11
    if(m=="Dec")return 12
}
{
    y=$1
    m=$2
    d=$3
    split($4,t,":")
    h=t[1]
    min=t[2]
    printf("%s%02d%02d%02d%02d\n",y,m2m(m),d,h,min)
}'
```

Notes:

- `srand` (not to be confused with `rand`) is returning the previous seed when called.
- When no argument is passed, `srand` is using the "time of the day" as seed.
- As `srand` is initialized internally under Solaris `nawk`, the first `srand()` call does return the time of the day, i.e. the number of seconds elapsed since the epoch.
- If you want a strictly portable way, you need to run a first srand() call before getting its return value but this is not required under Solaris.
- This is portable (i.e. POSIX) unlike using `truss`.

Comment: srand is a random number generator.  I don't see how this gets me the date 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Originally I had formed a response that works nicely on Linux, but not on Solaris.  This is much longer now, with the original answer below.

To do this purely in the shell, on Solaris, using only the `date` function, is possible.  Kind of.  You would have to create some shell functions as well to help out with the subtraction of days from a given date.

Using the functions below, you could do the following to get the desired results:

```
$ mydate="$(date '+%Y%m%d')"
$ hours="$(date '+%H')"
$ echo "$(date_subtract "${mydate}" 30)${hours}" | adb
```

or something like that...

On Solaris, the `date` command only provides Gregorian dates.  This is harder to work with for the purpose of this question, so I created a shell function, `gregorian_to_julian` which can convert a date in 'YYYYMMDD' format to a Julian date of 'YYYYDDD'.

```
function gregorian_to_julian {
    # "Expecting input as YYYYMMDD."
    typeset gregorian_date=$1
    typeset _year=$(echo "${gregorian_date}" | cut -c1-4)
    typeset _month=$(echo "${gregorian_date}" | cut -c5-6)
    typeset _day=$(echo "${gregorian_date}" | cut -c7-8)

    typeset days
    days[01]=31
    days[02]=$(( days[01] + 28 ))
    if (( _year % 4 == 0 )) && (( _year % 100 != 0 )) || (( _year % 400 == 0 )); then
        days[02]=$(( days[01] + 29 ))
    fi
    days[03]=$(( 31 + days[02] ))
    days[04]=$(( 30 + days[03] ))
    days[05]=$(( 31 + days[04] ))
    days[06]=$(( 30 + days[05] ))
    days[07]=$(( 31 + days[06] ))
    days[08]=$(( 31 + days[07] ))
    days[09]=$(( 30 + days[08] ))
    days[10]=$(( 31 + days[09] ))
    days[11]=$(( 30 + days[10] ))

    typeset julian_date=0
    case "${_month}" in
        "01") julian_date=$_day ;;
        "02") julian_date=$(( days[01] + _day )) ;;
        "03") julian_date=$(( days[02] + _day )) ;;
        "04") julian_date=$(( days[03] + _day )) ;;
        "05") julian_date=$(( days[04] + _day )) ;;
        "06") julian_date=$(( days[05] + _day )) ;;
        "07") julian_date=$(( days[06] + _day )) ;;
        "08") julian_date=$(( days[07] + _day )) ;;
        "09") julian_date=$(( days[08] + _day )) ;;
        "10") julian_date=$(( days[09] + _day )) ;;
        "11") julian_date=$(( days[10] + _day )) ;;
        "12") julian_date=$(( days[11] + _day )) ;;
    esac
    julian_date="${_year}${julian_date}"
    echo "${julian_date}"
}
```

Understanding that the OP wants the date formatted as a Gregorian date, I created a second function, `julian_to_gregorian` which converts the Julian date back.

```
function julian_to_gregorian {
    # "Expecting input as YYYYDDD."
    #set -x
    typeset julian_date=$1

    typeset _year="$(echo "${julian_date}" | cut -c1-4)"
    typeset _month=""
    typeset julian_day="$(echo "${julian_date}" | cut -c5-7)"
    typeset -RZ2 _day=0
    typeset days
    days[01]=31
    days[02]=$(( days[01] + 28 ))
    if (( _year % 4 == 0 )) && (( _year % 100 != 0 )) || (( _year % 400 == 0 )); then
        days[02]=$(( days[01] + 29 ))
    fi
    days[03]=$(( 31 + days[02] ))
    days[04]=$(( 30 + days[03] ))
    days[05]=$(( 31 + days[04] ))
    days[06]=$(( 30 + days[05] ))
    days[07]=$(( 31 + days[06] ))
    days[08]=$(( 31 + days[07] ))
    days[09]=$(( 30 + days[08] ))
    days[10]=$(( 31 + days[09] ))
    days[11]=$(( 30 + days[10] ))

    if (( days[11] < julian_day )); then    _month="12"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[11] ));
    elif (( days[10] < julian_day )); then  _month="11"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[10] ));
    elif (( days[09] < julian_day )); then  _month="10"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[09] ));
    elif (( days[08] < julian_day )); then  _month="09"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[08] ));
    elif (( days[07] < julian_day )); then  _month="08"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[07] ));
    elif (( days[06] < julian_day )); then  _month="07"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[06] ));
    elif (( days[05] < julian_day )); then  _month="06"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[05] ));
    elif (( days[04] < julian_day )); then  _month="05"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[04] ));
    elif (( days[03] < julian_day )); then  _month="04"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[03] ));
    elif (( days[02] < julian_day )); then  _month="03"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[02] ));
    elif (( days[01] < julian_day )); then  _month="02"; _day=$(( julian_day - days[01] ));
    else
        _month="01"; _day=${julian_day};
    fi
    echo "${_year}${_month}${_day}"
}
```

A third function, `date_subtract`, takes a Gregorian date, converts it to Julian, does the date math, and converts back to Gregorian.

```
function date_subtract {
    typeset julian_from_date=$(gregorian_to_julian "$1")
    typeset number_of_days=$2
    typeset julian_year=$(echo "${julian_from_date}" | cut -c1-4)
    typeset julian_days=$(echo "${julian_from_date}" | cut -c5-7)
    typeset leap_year="FALSE"
    if (( julian_days - number_of_days > 0 )); then
        (( julian_days -= number_of_days ))
    else
        (( julian_year -= 1 ))

        if (( julian_year % 4 == 0 )) && (( julian_year % 100 != 0 )) || (( julian_year % 400 == 0 )); then
            leap_year="TRUE"
        fi
        if [[ "${leap_year}" == "TRUE" ]]; then
            (( julian_days = julian_days + 366 - number_of_days ))
        else
            (( julian_days = julian_days + 365 - number_of_days ))
        fi
    fi
    typeset gregorian_date=$(julian_to_gregorian "${julian_year}${julian_days}")
    echo "${gregorian_date}"
}
```

**EDIT:** The following works nicely on Linux.   And is much simpler.

If you need the date formatted as `YYMMDDHH` then that is simple enough, as @FrankH. pointed out in his comment:

```
date +"%Y%m%d%H"
```

The trickier part is calculating the date 30 days ago, which seems to be your intent.  The `date` command can take the seconds since the epoch and convert that to a date string.  This is done with the `-d` flag. e.g.

```
$ date -d @123456789
Thu Nov 29 15:33:09 CST 1973
```

So, if you need the date for thirty days ago, we can take this principle and do a little math to get the needed value.

Note that `date '+%s'` gives us seconds since the epoch.

```
$ date -d @$(( $(date '+%s') - $((60 * 60 * 24 * 30 )) )) '+%Y%m%d%H'
2014011211
```

If you need to pipe that date string to `adb` then you can surround the command with $(...).

```
echo $( date -d @$(( $(date '+%s') - $((60 * 60 * 24 * 30 )) )) '+%Y%m%d%H' ) | adb
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Solaris doesn't have date -d. `date: illegal option -- d`

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was using a linux server to test that out.  I see that Solaris doesn't provide the `'+%s'` format either, so fail on multiple counts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Solaris 11, the answer is easy, because its `ksh` is `ksh93`. The [Solaris 11 ksh man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/ksh-1.html) has this info about `printf`:

```
A %(date-format)T format can be use to treat an argument as a date/time string
and to format the date/time according to the date-format as defined for the
date(1) command.
```

The allowable date/time string formats aren't specified in the `ksh` man page, but are (somewhat) mentioned in the [AST tm(3) man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man3/tmx.html). A wide variety are accepted. In particular, this will do what you want:

```
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d%H)T\n" 
2014021118
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d%H)T\n" now
2014021118
$ printf "%(%Y%m%d%H)T\n" "30 days ago"
2014011218
```

Comment: Dang, we're using Solaris 10